# Django pagination on model with foreign key

Tags: django, pagination, django-pagination

Post and comment models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Class view of post detail

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'posts/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        return queryset
```

In the template I do something like this

```
{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
{% comment.content %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this approach, all the comments are shown in the post detail page. However, I want to paginate the comments of a post so that I can do pagination on comments and not show the whole list of comments.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paginators are provided in django be default. You can paginate comments by overriding your `get_context_data` method like this.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    comments = context['post'].comment_set.all()
    paginator = Paginator(comments, per_page=50)
    page_number = 1  # get it from query sting or whatever the way you want
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
    context['comments'] = page
    return context
```

you can render commnets in template by looping over them like this.

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    {# render comment here. #}
{% endfor %}
```

for more information about rendering pagination controls, please consult [official docs about paginators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/) here.